# Should the contractor be able to drill holes in a quartz countertop?

Tags: drill, countertops

Sometime in the future I'll be having quartz countertops installed in a new kitchen. They'll be silestone's eco line of countertops. Should the contractor doing the install, assuming he's a professional, be able to cut small holes in the counter top to install things like the faucet or a soap dispenser? Or are those sorts of things normally done at the factory/manufacturer etc?

I've seen diamond coated drills bits that are supposed to be used for things like this so I'm guessing any reasonable contractor that does this for a living should be able to drill some holes.

Thanks

Comment: Ask him. That's the only way to know for certain.

Comment: I'm trying to gauge how professional/qualified he is, so that's why I am asking if this is something that would be typically done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sink holes (faucet/soap/whatever) are almost always done on site.  The actual sink cutout is already done at the shop and the company doing the install probably does not want to risk even further the chance of cracking/breaking.

Anyone with a drill and a $15 diamond circle bit can cut these holes out in a couple mins per hole.  If they can't they shouldn't be installing your countertops.

If your contractor says they are a pro at installing countertops and they DO NOT do this then it is equivalent to a plumber saying they don't hook up shower heads - get another installer.  The holes should be drilled before it is on your cabinets (often these holes might not leave much room from behind for a drill to go straight down).  You do not want to have another guy come out and drill these - if something went wrong who would be at fault?

Comment: Do pro installers just use a hand drill or is some type of press preferred?

Comment: Hand drill and hose.  I drill probably 20 of these a year and I am by no means a pro counter installer.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know. I've had a horrible experience with this contractor - completely mis-manages the whole project so if he comes back and says he can't/won't drill the holes, i just wanted to know if that was an unreasonable response.

Comment: @merk - If he is that bad and the counter is already in - I would seriously say skip it.  Call up a local granite place and ask them to come by when they get a chance.  I am sure that $50 you spend for a couple holes will be worth it.  A bad contractor may damage counters or put the holes in the wrong place/shape.  But the project is also very DIYish if you feel like buying a diamond bit and sandpaper.

Comment: Counters are not in yet - hell the kitchen is not in yet. But I think they might be actually installing the cabinets next week, so hopefully the counter top isn't far behind. Then again they probably wont actually order the countertop until a week after the cabinets are installed.
I definitely do not want to try doing this myself since if I mess up, that's going to be a very expensive mistake. I'd rather let them do it and if they mess up, it's on them to make good.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question at the time of template with your countertop. The answer should be "YES" by your contractor. If he refused I would find another one. I've seen people totally screw up a top not properly knowing how to drill into surfaces. Especially if they aren't holding the drill correctly.